# MFC Control in a Qt Tab Widget

Tags: c++, qt, mfc, qt-mfc-migration

I'm working on a project that is using the [Qt/MFC Migration Framework](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/appdev/add-on-products/catalog/4/Windows/qtwinmigrate) and I'm trying to reuse some existing MFC controls inside of a Qt dialog.

Does anyone know if it is possible to insert an MFC control (CDialog or CWnd) inside of a QTabWidget. Right now we're doing the opposite, we have an MFC dialog with a tab control which is populated with a mix of MFC tabs (CDialog) and Qt tabs ([QWinWidget](http://doc.trolltech.com/solutions/4/qtwinmigrate/qwinwidget.html)). However, this approach is giving me a headache because the QWinWidget controls are not properly being drawn nor are they receiving focus or keyboard input correctly. I am hoping that using a Qt dialog with a QTabWidget will work better than this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you use `QWinWidget`, you must have come cross [`QWinHost`](http://doc.trolltech.com/solutions/4/qtwinmigrate/qwinhost.html)? Simply use `QWinHost` as the pages for a `QTabWidget`:

```
HWND w = ...;
QTabWidget * tw = new QTabWidget;
QWinHost * wh = new QWinHost;
wh->setWindow( w );
tw->addTab( tr("Page with Windows Control"), wh );
```